# How to exclude the area occupied by MenuStrip from the client area of a form?

Tags: c#, winforms

The area occupied by MainMenu is excluded from the client area of a form. However the area occupied by MenuStrip is included in the client area of a form  As result if I will draw a string at coordinates 0, 0 then it will be overlapped by the MenuStrip.

How to make such a way that the area occupied by a MenuStrip would be excluded from the client area?

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of your form?

Comment: MenuStrip has an Height property, same for the MenuStripItem returned when you add an item to the MenuStrip

Comment: @JWiley There is no need to include a screenshot. Simply try to use at first MainMenu and then MenuStrip and compare the results. You can simply output MessageBox.Show(this.ClientRectangle.ToString() + "\n" + this.Bounds); and compare results.

Comment: @Steve And I can to set the height to zero?

Comment: Docs says that you can get/set this value, but a sample experiment seems to indicate that whatever value you set it is ignored.

Comment: Can't you simply place a Panel on the part of the form that you want to draw on, and draw on the Panel instead of drawing on the Form?

Comment: @RenniePet No I am not going to do such things. The question can be asked in another way What is the reason of different behaviours of MainMenu and MenuStrip? What should be set in MenuStrip that it would behave as MainMenu?

Comment: The MenuStrip is just another control. It is added in client area. You can move it around like a regular control

Answer (score 2):

That's pretty easy.

- Create a TableLayoutPanel.
- Set Dock: Fill.
- Delete the last column. Now you have only 1 column.
- Set row1 to 23-25px and row2 to autosize.
- Now Drag and drop your menu into the first cell/row and your "client-area" (Panel?)
  to the second one.

If you have some troubles to drag and drop them just use the document outline.

**Edit:** Have you tried a simple `menustrip1.SendToBack();`  to change the z-order?
Or a `Control.BringToFront();` for your string/etc.?

Comment: It is too artificially. I am not going to do such things only that to exclude the area occupied by a MenuStrip from the client area of a form. I think there should be another natural solution.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, You have only two options -

1. Do the math yourself. (**not** my preferred solution).
2. Use a simple panel as container for all your controls, except for the menu item itself. (my preferred solution, knowing what I know about winforms, only reasonable option which comes to mind).

Note that the second option is slightly different from other answer suggesting TableLayoutPanel..
IMHO, a simple panel would suffice.. as long as you take care of the Z-Order.

**EDIT** - Saw other comments on your question which were collapsed before.. After reading your comments, it is clear you have already excluded these options.. Sorry.